# The timer is not triggered when you click play in the HTML videoplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery

in short I have a script that when clicked in the div #video loads a script with a timer, after which it pauses the video on the page. The problem occurs when I click the "play" button (to start the video). The script does not load. If I click anywhere else within diva #video - reads.

Is there any function to do this, I do not know (pseudocode): play().onclick? How can I do this?

```js
$("#video").on("click", function() {
 
  setTimeout(function () {
  var my_video = document.getElementById("video");
  $('#overlay').show();
  $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
  my_video.pause(); 
  }, 22000);
 
});
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>

<div id="video_player">
  <video id="video" controls>
    <source src="videosource" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```